# Adding a string in an int array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with integer numbers and I would like to know the way to put a string "x" in some cells.
I am trying this,but i know that its impossible in this way:

```
array[i][j]="x";
```

Comment: The short answer: **don't**. Don't mix types in arrays or you're heading for a world of hurt. The longer answer will depend on what problem you're trying to solve, because surely there's a better way to solve it. Give us more information please, and we'll likely be able to help you find a better answer.

Comment: A way to do such a thing is to use a list of objects but this is a workaround. I think you don't have realised what is the problem you are trying to solve or at least you don't give enough info.

Comment: thanks for all the answers.I just realised that I can solve my problem with just printing the "x"s and not adding them in the array.

Comment: @DiVeRsi0n: the lesson to learn from this is that your question was incomplete, that you were asking a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question, where you're fixated on how to implement a wrong solution. To avoid having the same issue in the future, don't fixate so much on your solution but on the overall problem, and try to ask a more informative question, so that we can get a gist of the overall problem. Glad you've found a solution though.

Comment: I think that i took my lesson...

Answer (score 4):

You can't. If an array is `int[]`, you can't add a `String` to it because Java is [strongly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). You might want to use `String[]` instead and store intergers as strings as well.

```
stringArray[i][j] = String.valueOf(yourInteger);
```

If you want to get the integers back from the `String` array to operate with them:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i][j])
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** do this, because if the array is defined to containt integers, it doesn't make sense to add a `String` to it.

Something you can do (but you should use it if you *really know* what you are doing) is to add the Unicode value of a character in the `String`:

```
array[i][j] = "x".codePointAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is strongly typed, then you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer as has been discussed in comments is not to consider doing what you're considering -- trying to mix types in an array or collection. You should strive to avoid using Object typed arrays and to avoid using non-generic or Object type collections as by doing this your compiler no longer has the ability to check for key compile-time mis-matched type errors. For the same reason, you should avoid mis-using String as a way to get around this problem, a classic anti-pattern. A much better solution is to try to solve the overall problem so that your program won't even need these considerations.